# Changing the url of the redirected page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form and the link of this form is as follows:
/creator-application-form

After this form is filled and submitted, I want it to be updated as follows:
/creator-application-form-thank-you

To do this, I wrote the link that I want to be updated when we send the form directly in the related post method in web php, but when I did this, I got the following error.

[image]

The part I changed in web.php used to be like this:

```
Route::post('/creator-application-form',[CreatorController::class,'sendCreatorApplication']);
```

Right now it's like this:

```
Route::post('/creator-application-form-thank-you',[CreatorController::class,'sendCreatorApplication']);
```

How can I do the job of changing this url as I want after this form is submitted? Can you help me with this?

Comment: Are you asking how to specify the URL that your form submits the data _to_? That happens via its `action` attribute.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I wanted to ask him. After entering the form, a page appears and I want to write the link of that page at the end -thanks. Probably done as you said. But since I have not done this before, there is no information on how to do it. Can you tell me how to convey this as you say?

Comment: Not with the minimal info you have given so far, we have not seen where you are creating this form.

Comment: Do all your validation/form handling in `/creator-application-form` - then if all values are valid and data has been posted/saved redirect to your thank-you-page (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well you want that after you send your form redirect to route:

```
Route::post('/creator-application-form-thank-you',[CreatorController::class,'sendCreatorApplication']);
```

first of all to do this, you should create route `get`, not `post` routes post if to send any data.

therefore you can do route get route:

Route::get('/creator-application-form-thank-you',[CreatorController::class,'sendCreatorApplication']);

And in your controller function `sendCreatorApplication` you can show view:

```
return view('your blade')
```